# Кнопка под сообшением бота в Telegram

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать вот такую кнопку ("Названия фильмов") у бота в телеграм на c#:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делаете клавиатуру из одной кнопки и готово. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1410987/373567

Comment: @aepot клавиатуру инлайн я то создал, а как обработать нажатие?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, почти не имеющий отношения к изначальному

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new []
        {
            InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11"),
        });
        
        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
            chatId: message.Chat.Id,
            text: "A message with an inline keyboard markup",
            replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
            cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Где

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new []
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11"),
    });
```

Создание клавиатуры, а

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new []
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "1.1", callbackData: "11"),
    });

    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: message.Chat.Id,
        text: "A message with an inline keyboard markup",
        replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Отправляет сообщение с прикрепленной кнопкой.